# How do Pseudo-residuals work in a Gradient Boosting Machine (GBM)?

Tags: statistics, scikit-learn, gbm

So in a GBM, each tree predicts the 'pseudo-residuals' of the prior tree [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting).

I'm not sure exactly how these 'pseudo-residuals' work but I wonder how this plays out when you have a combination of:

1. Binary classification problem
2. Low response rate
3. A reasonably low signal-to-noise ratio

In the example below, we have all 3.  I calculate residuals as `Actual - Probability` and since the response is binary, you end up with this highly bi-modal distribution which is nearly identical to the response.

Decreasing the response rate further exacerbates the bi-modal distribution since the probabilities are closer to zero and, hence, the distributions are even closer to either 0 or 1.

**So I have a few questions here**:

1. How exactly would pseudo residuals be calculated in this example? *(I am fairly sure this is wrong, aside from just the fact that the initial tree models difference from the global mean)*
2. Would the second tree be nearly identical to the first as a result?
3. Are successive trees in a GBM more similar for problems with lower response rates?
4. Does down-sampling on non-response inherently change the model as a result?

.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

train_percent = 0.8
num_rows = 10000
remove_rate = 0.1

# Generate data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=num_rows, flip_y=0.55)

# Remove response rows to make sample unbalanced
remove = (np.random.random(len(y)) > remove_rate) & (y == 1)
X, y = X[~remove], y[~remove]
print("Response Rate: " + str(sum(y) / float(len(y))))

# Get train/test samples (data is pre-shuffled)
train_rows = int(train_percent * len(X))
X_train , y_train = X[:train_rows], y[:train_rows]
X_test , y_test = X[train_rows:], y[train_rows:]

# Fit a simple decision tree
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]

# Calculate roc auc
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, pred)
print("ROC AUC: " + str(roc_auc))

# Plot residuals
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.hist(y_test - pred);
plt.title('Residuals')
```

[image]